# How to parse doc/docx file using javascript, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm developing an application which creates quizzes. Teachers will create quizzes to evaluate knowledge of pupils. I created simple API using NodeJS and web part of the application using AngularJS.

But it is quite difficult for old teachers to type all question and answers.

I think it would be better to add an opportunity for them to upload doc/docx files which will parse and aggregate all questions and answers into a quiz.

Does anybody know any solutions which work on Angular and NodeJS ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment but I really advise against it. doc/docx don't really have a fixed structure and you don't really want to support all the styling/other options of these formats. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: How is the system right now, do you have a teacher-only section of the site where teacher enter the questions and answers?

Comment: Dekel, if it works wrong, I can give them a doc template where they can type data and then upload.

nicovank, First of all, I want to create a private page for teachers, then after optimisation and improvement I would like to share it.

Comment: Why not RTF? Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesMGreene/2b6Lc/ (**WARNING**: I have't tested it and don't know how the output is and if it is reliable **at all**!)

Comment: @DenisEvseev yes I think your best option is to create a private page for them with an question editor, then upload the questions to a database and display them to the students.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think there is a python lib that works with node to parse new office files, I'd suggest you to use excel and export `.csv` files which are basically test and could be parsed by you easily.

Teachers could still use the familiar excel file,the just have to follow a specific layout.

You have to define some way of how the questions must look like so you can parse them correctly. Assuming every question has four possible answers, I'd suggest five columns

`|Question|Correct Answer|Answer B|Answer C|AnswerD|`

You could then just randomize the order of the answers when dispalying them...

**EDIT**

Second idea, just provide a really easy UI to add and manage questions, shouldn't be too hard to get something *teacher-proof*

Comment: That is just too much constraints for the teacher. And using CSV makes impossible to use any kind of styling (bold, ...)

Comment: Good idea, I'll try to implement it if I don't find anything more useful

Comment: Instead of CSV, you could use Excel XML. I wrote a code a while back to convert a table into Excel XML. Maybe I can hunt for it?

Comment: Ismael Miguel if it is possible could you please share it. Thx!